# Finding underlying distribution of proportion data

Tags: count-data, curve-fitting

I have a large dataset of count data --- count of positive cases and total number of cases distributed by distance (in meters).  The empirical distribution of proportions and beginning of data are attached (there are 444260 rows, red line is the proportion of cumulative sum)
I want to find an underlying, theoretical distribution that fits best the data. I would like to have a function that estimate probability of the positive case given distance in meters.

However, due to sparsity of data (small total number of cases on a specific distance), some proportions on far distance are high because of randomness.
What would be the best way to transform dataset, to smooth the distribution?  I’ve tried various binning methods, Fayyad Multi-Interval Discretization, log scale, but all those methods seems to “rough” to capture the steep decline on beginning.

What would be the best candidates for theoretical distribution --- Poisson, negative binomial, Pareto, …?

---

```
    D   K   CNT
 1  0   167 1622
 2  1   0   12
 3  2   0   1
 4  3   0   1
 5  4   0   1
 6  5   0   3
 7  6   1   7
 8  7   0   8
 9  8   2   14
 10 9   1   16
 11 10  0   10
 12 11  0   17
 13 12  1   13
 14 13  1   31
 15 14  0   36
 16 15  0   57
 17 16  1   77
 18 17  3   60
 19 18  0   31
 20 19  0   56
```

[image: Distance-Proportion plot]